# In Robot Framework, page is not loading fully in headless chrome in ubuntu:18.04

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, robotframework, ubuntu-18.04, google-chrome-headless

**About Web Application Under Test:**
Application is developed using Angular JS and React.

**Problem:**
Using Robot Framework from home page, navigated to other page. Page is partially loaded and some of the components are not loaded.(**Page is developed using both angular and react code**)

**Settings Used:**
Below **chrome options** are used to launch a browser

```
Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    --headless
Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
```

**Versions Used:**

- ubuntu:18.04
- Python 3.6.9
- robotframework-4.0
- robotframework-selenium2library-3.0.0
- gitlab 13.10

**Note:**
With above settings, ***Working in windows machine in both Headless and GUI, Only in CI/CD it is not working***

Anyone here faced the same problem, Please help on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Add please what kind of error Robotframework is returning.

Comment: @BoburMeliev Actually I'm not getting any error, only thing is page partially loaded. So I couldn't move to next page as expected element is not visible. 
I tried with sleep up to 15 mins, Reload Page, but nothing worked.

**Note:**
Page has multiple API calls, so it fetch and set in UI, not sure whether those calls are triggered in headless chrome. Because I don't see loading icon in partially loaded page.

Comment: If the page is not fully loading *only* in CI, open the page locally in your own machine, copy the requests (for example, at least firefox has copy as curl) and then try to run those curl commands in the CI machine separately and see if you get responses.. It could very well be that CI boxes do not have same network access, for example firewall blocks outgoing requests to particular hosts and those cause error which can break the rendering and/or rest of the asset fetching.

Comment: PS. robotframework-selenium2library *is not what you should be using*  - it acts as meta package that will fetch *real* robotframework-seleniumlibrary ..

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you are using old version of Selenium library, current the latest version if 5.1.3. Try to install latest version

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-selenium2library
```

Then update your browser and browser driver.

Comment: No luck, I tried with latest seleniumlibrary 5.1.3

Comment: There is another option to install Xvfb and use non-headless browser.